# Page redirect for incorrect Razor view loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on error handling and user experience for a single page application.  I am using razor views and have everything hooked up, but want to account for any possibility. If the model that is passed to the view doesn't have an expected value, it throws a generic error. [image: generic error].

I would like to be able to reroute the page to a more friendly error page, with some detail about the issue, however I haven't been able to figure out a way to catch a bad model between it being sent to the view and the page attempting to load it.

My question is, is there a way to recognize when a razor view will throw this error before it happens? and if so, how can I intercept it and reroute to an error page?

As requested, Editing to show the controller object.

```
    public ActionResult GetStoreRequests(string storeId, string storeName)
    {
        var requestListCustomRenderer = new RequestListCustomRenderer();
        var storeRequestRenderedResult = new StoreRequestsRenderedResult();

        var storeRequestResponse = _repository.GetStoreRequestInfo(storeId);
        StoreRequestWithStoreName dto = _repository.GetStoreRequests(storeRequestResponse, storeId, storeName);
        storeRequestRenderedResult.ChargeOffCount = dto.StoreRequestList.ChargeOffListRemovalList.Count();
        storeRequestRenderedResult.ExtensionCount = dto.StoreRequestList.AgreementExtensionList.Count();
        storeRequestRenderedResult.InventoryCount = dto.StoreRequestList.InventoryExchangeList.Count();
        storeRequestRenderedResult.StoreId = dto.StoreId;
        storeRequestRenderedResult.StoreName = dto.StoreName;
        storeRequestRenderedResult.RenderedStoreRequests = requestListCustomRenderer.RenderStoreRequests(dto);
        return PartialView("ApprovalView", storeRequestRenderedResult);
    }
```

Comment: are you shure that you get View? Looks loke you get json object with ajax. Can you show your Controller example?

Comment: Read about ovveride OnException filter: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/731913/Exception-Handling-in-MVC

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want just **try/catch** your `PartialView`?

Like this:

```
try
{
    PartialViewResult res = PartialView("ApprovalView", storeRequestRenderedResult);
    return res;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about using a try catch, but I am a little unsure of handling it.  The model I am passing is complete as far as it knows, and won't throw errors until the razor attempts to access the properties.

Comment: `PartialView` is rendering your View with View Engine that you use. So error should handling well.